# Polynomial and complex roots

Tags: complex-analysis

$p(x) = x^8+2x^4+4$

I have to find:
- the roots
- which roots are complex conjugate to each other
- then split it into linear factors with complex coefficients
- find the factorisation in $R$ (real numbers)

After substitution I got these roots:

$x_0=4^\frac{1}{4}e^{i\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{2{\pi}k}4}$

$x_0=4^\frac{1}{4}e^{-i\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{2{\pi}k}4}$

Where $k$ is from $0$ to $3$.

Now how do I split the polynomial into linear factors?
Should I just multiply my roots out?
How do I find the factorisation in $R$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Simply write the polynomial as $$p(x)=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)(x-x_5)(x-x_6)(x-x_7)(x-x_8)$$
   where $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8$ are the $8$ roots that you have found.

It will serve your job of expressing $p(x)$ as a product of linear factors.

2. There are $4$ pairs of complex conjugate roots. The $2$ $x_0$ that you have found out are conjugate to each other. You can find the $4$ pairs of complex conjugate roots by putting the $4$ values of $k$.
3. From the above expression of $p(x)$, multiply the factors containing conjugate roots. You will get $4$ quadratic factors and that is your answer to the $4$th question.

Comment: Would the angles negate each other then and just leave, for instance, only leaving $x=4^\frac{1}{4}*4^\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: Yes. they would.